# Nginx 10 minute timeout occurring

Tags: amazon-web-services, timeout, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have an AWS-hosted web application that initiates a long-running server process (more than 10 mintues). An Nginx reverse proxy server sits between the application load balancer (ALB) and the service. Both the Nginx server and the service reside within separate Kubernetes pods running on an EC2 instance.

I'm experiencing an issue with a connection being closed. The Nginx logs show a HTTP 499 error:

> (][05/Dec/2022:12:02:27 +0000] "POST -------------- HTTP/1.1" 499 0
> "https://------------.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X
> 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0
> Safari/537.36")

The issue is repeatable and occurs exactly 10 minutes after the request was initiated. Despite my having set the ALB, Nginx, and SQL Alchemy timeouts to be much longer than 10 minutes, I suspect a timeout is occurring with a default value of 10 minutes, but I can't figure out where.

Nginx is the product I'm least familiar with and so I suspect that I have failed to make the necessary timeout configs in its conf file. I have set this:

```
proxy_read_timeout          20m;
```

Can anyone suggest where in the system the default timeout is occurring?